# Cast a column as Boolean in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, casting, boolean

I have a field ('done') in the Database which is boolean. The function which GET/ the rows doesn't return a json with that field as boolean but it returns 1 or 0.

```
function getTasks() {
$sql = "SELECT id,task_name,done FROM tarea ORDER BY id";
try {
    $db = getConnection();
    $stmt = $db->query($sql);
    $tasks= $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $db = null;
    echo json_encode($tasks);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
}
}
```

How can I get THAT column ('done' column) as boolean? I mean, Is posible to cast a column with PDO::PARAM_BOOL ??

Here is my sample of UPDATE that inserts booleans in the database and it works perfectly:

```
function updateTask($id) {
$request = Slim::getInstance()->request();
$body = $request->getBody();
$task = json_decode($body);
$sql = "UPDATE tarea SET task_name=:task_name, done=:done WHERE id=:id";

try {
    $db = getConnection();
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam("task_name", $task->task_name);

    $stmt->bindParam("done", $task->done,PDO::PARAM_BOOL);  // cast before execute

    $stmt->bindParam("id", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $db = null;
    echo json_encode($task);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
}
}
```

Comment: [This might be of interest](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8393090/2518525)

Comment: it doesnt work for me, that example you've mentioned is for INSERT and UPDATE, not for SELECT...

Comment: You cant use bindParam on output, you can cast it in the results.  Or you can use a custom class to populate, but that is just a wrapper around my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In SQL there are no booleans really, as you notice the `1` and `0` .

The right terminology is `BIT` field. you should not try to modify it, if you retrieve it as `1` and `0` then you should insert it as `1` or `0`.

Also note that the JSON in the catch will produce is not valid, never build json manually. So change :

```
echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
```

to

```
echo json_encode(array('error'=>$e->getMessage()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I know Im a bit late on this, but I wanted to add my 2 cents as these best practices will help everyone and I think its a good way to keep things simple:

Simple message: Keep Data types as strict and explicit as possible and call them exactly what they are.

Mysql does not have an explicit boolean data type so we use TINYINT(1) in the database with 1/0.
If we are using an integer datatype I dont think it is good practice to bind a parameter as a boolean when it really is not
Although MYSQL converts true/false perfectly to 1/0 internally, I feel 1/0 should be explicitly bound as integers

PGSQL Has an explicit True/false data type where you can pass true/false directly
PGSQL has lots of other options such as 'yes','no' which need to be wrapped around quotes making it even more confusing as string values are interpreted as boolean. Thats wrong, they should be considered strings as that's what they are.

```
$sql->bindParam(':done',1,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->bindParam(':done',true,PDO::PARAM_BOOL);
//In my code I have created some wrapper,
//Explicit true/false & adds PARAM_BOOL
$sql->bind('done',$done,'bool');
//Expects only 1 or 0
$sql->bind('done',$done,'bit');
```

I have just built a library on top of PDO which enforces strict types, this allows you to explicitly type check data types and automatically select the appropriate PDO Constant, so you always have the correct type casted beforehand based on the driver

Answer (score -1):

Really simple,

```
$tasks = array();
while( false !== ( $task = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) ) ){
   $task->done = (bool)$task->done;
   $tasks[] = $task;
}
```

if that doesn't work you can do this too

```
if(intval($task->done)){
   $task->done = true;
}else{
   $task->done = false;
}
```

Etc..

Comment: Ok, let's try! Thanks! :D

Comment: Impressive! sometimes simple things do the work.
I've just replace "$tasks= $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);" for the first piece of your code

Comment: @Frankistan if this did helped you kindly check that mark on the left side of this answer. always accept answers that worked for you. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @Frankistan - glad I could help.  Often it's too easy to let things get overly complicated.  Always try to do things the "approved" way and if that fails just do it in the simplest way you can.  Often you will get better performance that way too.